# Android performance Maintain json files or an sqlite database?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

Hello this is probably a typical question but i cant seem to find a clear answer?

I have a backend application that will serve data in json form.

The data will be in form [code] [name].

The data sets might vary from 100-2000 rows.

What would be best...

Store directly these json responses as files and then parse them if they exist?
Or store them in the android database?

In each case the data does not change that often maybe 1 per week.

Which way  would be the faster and which more efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think database is much more preferable way here. Text rows even in quantities like 2000 on smart phones better not to be handled in text I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the Sqlite db too, I'm quite sure that it's much faster than using basic file i/o.

Comment: Why would it be faster? (I understand that if you need to do queries it would be; just not if it's simple lookup for different files)